# jQuery - Show only visible span

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jquery visible selector but it seems to still show both spans. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
 <span id="description">
   Test   
   <span style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">Hide</span>
 </span>
```

jQuery

```
 alert($("#description").filter(':visible').text());
```

**JSFIDDLE**:
http://jsfiddle.net/fak2qtwL/1/

Comment: What result did you expect?  The `span` matching the `#description` selector is visible, and the hidden one is nested in a visible one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the way it works. Your span contains a child element that is not visible but your parent span is visible. So the result you get is normal.  To work in the way you want you need two different `span` like this:

```js
alert($("span:visible").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="description">Test</span>
<span style="display:none;">Hide</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `text()` method returns all the text content inside matching selector - That includes the text inside their children too. Your selector matches the `span#description` since it is visible, hence it returns the text inside it's children as well, regardless of their visibility.